# How to set column=null if the same column is used in where clause? [SQL]

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

this select statement works pretty well:

```
select b.* 
from tmp_table b
where b.col1 not in (select a.col9 from another_table a); -- returns col1=1234 data
```

but this update statement is showing error.

i was trying to set `col1` as null if current `col1` value does not exist in `another_table`

```
update tmp_table b
set b.col1=null
where b.col1 not in (select a.col9 from another_table a);
```

error:

```
ORA-01407: cannot update ("DBUSERNAME"."TMP_TABLE"."COL1") to null
```

sample tmp_table:

```
 col1  | col2 
 ----- | ----- 
 1234  | fish
 5678  | tiger
```

sample another_table:

```
 col8  | col9 
 ----- | ----- 
 air   | 0000
 land  | 5678
```

expected result:

```
 col1  | col2 
 ----- | ----- 
 (null)| fish
 5678  | tiger
```

Comment: Have you checked the column properties? Is the column nullable?
If I reproduce your problem with the same code it works.

Comment: problem is solved when i changed the column to nullable, thank you!